# Fix $PATH on Mac OS

Tags: macos, path

I was trying to add a dir to my path environment but somehow things went wrong and now the terminal wont even recongnize the 'ls' command.
How can I reset or fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it from another account, if needed by booting in single user mode: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492

This presumes that you are familiar with the basics of Unix shells.